# issue with dynamic checkboxes in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

so I'm trying to create multiple checkboxes based on the number of decks I have.
In this example, one of the decks is called fruit. these checkboxes look like:
[image]

so if a user presses the fruit button, all fruit objects are checked.
if a user presses a single button, that fruit will get marked.

But if I selected all fruits with the fruit button and then remove a single fruit like kiwi. it deletes it from the list entirely, but I just want to uncheck them:

**Example:**
[image]

But if I check a single object and uncheck that object, the problem is not occurring.

**Example:**
[image]

Here is my stack blitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pwgfng?file=src/app/app.component.ts
If someone would like to take a look at it.

If you have any questions, just ask. I'm happy to reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with reference to array.

When you select deck which isn't in `chosenDecks` yet this code run:

```
this.chosenDecks.push(selectedDeck);
```

so an deck from `allDecks` is being added along with array reference.

Later on you `splice` `types` array when an fruit is unselected:

```
this.chosenDecks[deckIndex].types.splice(typeIndex, 1);
```

Solution to prevent removing that fruit from `this.allDecks` array is:

```
this.chosenDecks.push({...selectedDeck, types: selectedDeck.types.slice()});
```

or any other that will copy array without reference :-)